# Saving view state in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, viewstate

When I change from portrait mode to landscape and back to portrait mode. `PickerView` size gets changed in portrait mode on back retaining. So how can I save the state of view so that picker size does not change.

Comment: are you added your Pickerview in to POpover..?

Comment: Its a problem of auto resizing of views and control.

Comment: i am not adding Pickerview in to POpover..

Comment: As iHungry said, check auto resizing in view, pickerview,...

Answer (score 2):

Select the `PickerView` Go to the size inspector -> autoSizing and unchecke the middle arrow
[image]